# dictionary.dat file keeps getting deleted when browsing site

Tags: multilingual, performance-optimization, patch-configuration

Whenever I publish my dictionary items, I see the dictionary.dat file getting created. However, whenever I browse the site, the file gets deleted. I can see that happen in real time.

What might be some good things to check / try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be this code that was present in one of my performance config patches:

```
<pipelines>
  <getTranslation>
    <patch:delete/>
  </getTranslation>
</pipelines>
```

Any time `Translate.Text()` was called, it would permanently delete the `dictionary.dat` file until the dictionary got published again.